# How can I detect whether my Facebook access token is invalid or not?

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I know about handling invalid access token by using exchange token method. But my question is how can I detect it as invalid?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-debug/

Comment: What is the backend you are using Rails, PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check using Graph API
    https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=INPUT_TOKEN&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)